# Trying to understand what is causing this JavaScript bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers, jquery-events

I have an element `X` that `onclick` initializes/updates a `printControl` as such:

```
printControl.init(tab, source, location, start_month, end_month, year);
```

Here is the relevant code for the `printControl`:

```
var printControl = {
  init: function(tab, source, location, start_month, end_month, year) {
    $(".print").click(function() {
      window.print();
    });
  ...
  }
  ...
```

Here's the bug.  When the user presses the `.print` element, the print menu will come up once.  However, if the element `X` has been clicked a specific number of times without the page having reloaded, then when the user presses the `.print` element, the default print menu will open that number of times.

Is this because a new `printControl` function is initialized on every click of `X`, and so when `.print` is actually clicked, it runs for every one of these functions?  Or is something else going on.  If so, how do I go about refactoring my code to fix this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed happening because are binding to the click event multiple times. To fix this before you bind the click handler unbind any existing handlers with

```
$(".print").off("click")
```

Comment: Thanks a ton... so is the problem what I thought it was?

Comment: @Hubrid Yes, the problem was caused by binding multiple times to the click handler. They stack  up so that if you bind the same function twice it will be called twice on the click event.